# How to access getter function in different form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms in one project/namespace that need to communicate with one another.  Form A creates an instance of form B; and form B needs to access a value in form A (seems simple enough).

I have created this type of functionality when building forms from the ground up in VB. This time I am working on a pre-existing project, and I cannot get form B to access form A's value.  What is causing this issue, and how could I solve it?

Thanks for the help!

I created a getter function in form A:

```
public string getID()
        {
            return txtID.Text;
        }
```

Then I try to access this method in form B:

```
string strID = getID();
```

The error I get is: "The name 'getID' does not exist in the current context"

Also, I tried accessing the function this way (but it did not work):

```
A.getID();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared an *instance* method (rather than a property for some reason, and ignoring .NET naming conventions, but hey...).

That means you need to call it on an *instance* of the form. So as a simple example:

```
FormA a = new FormA();
// Use a for a while, whatever
String id = a.getID();
```

Now as it's `FormA` that creates `FormB` itself, it probably just needs to pass a reference to itself to `FormB`, using `this`:

```
FormB formB = new FormB(this);

...

class FormB
{
    private FormA parent;

    internal FormB(FormA parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // Or parent.Id as it would normally be, as a property...
        string id = parent.getID(); 
    }
}
```

It's not usually a good idea to couple forms as closely as this though. Does `FormB` really need to get the value later? Perhaps `FormA` could just pass the ID to the constructor of `FormB` instead?

Comment: I did not paste the code I am working with in the question, rather an example to give an idea of what is going on.  Why would I want to create an instance of form A if it exists and created form B?

Comment: @Azzi: I was simply giving an example of calling an instance method. See my edited answer - whatever you do, FormB will need a reference to the relevant instance of FormA in order to call an instance method (or property). How it obtains that reference is up to you. It's important that you understand why it's necessary though - I suggest you actually put down GUIs for the moment and go back to the basics of C#. (GUIs are tricky enough on their own - it's good to learn one thing at a time in my opinion.)

Comment: Form B does need to get the value later.  I have accomplished this with a public getter in VB before.

Comment: @Azzi: Well then Form B needs a reference to the instance of FormA. It's as simple as that. You can't call an instance method without an instance to call it on. It's like asking: "What's a peron's birthday?" without specifying which person you're talking about. VB has probably been confusing things by assuming there'd only ever be one instance of the form.